# Perl scripts will not run in apache (Permission Denied)

Tags: apache, perl

I have LAMP installed on Ubuntu 14.04.1.

I want to be able to run cgi scripts from all directories that are within my website. So I added this to `/etc/apache2/apache.conf`

```
    <Directory /var/www/> 
          AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
          Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    </Directory>
```

I also did this edit in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf`

```
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py .pl
```

But now when i visit my script it says

> You don't have permission to access /hello.pl on this server.

But I have chmodded and chowned the script.. in fact look...

`ls -la hello.cgi
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 84 Jan 26 03:19 hello.pl`

Comment: You might want to define *everywhere* and depending on your answer, be prepared to receive a lot of people warning about security.  Also, did you try restarting your Apache server?

Comment: All directories and yes i have.

Comment: I also have tried to put it under `<Directory /var/www/>` but it wont work.

Comment: Yes I see, its working in cgi-bin, but my question is how to allow it in all directories. When i read through the documentation it says i just need to add the `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi` in `mime.conf` but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

*(Self answer by [Banned_User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3649259/banned-user) moved from question body)*

What I did was edit `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.example.com/` and add:

```
<Directory /var/www/www.example.com>
      Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```